# How avoid that duplicate subcomponents get created when pressing ALT-F12 twice?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I want to create a component composed of a `TLayout` that contains a `TRectangle`.

The `TRectangle` is created inside the component's constructor and has the `TLayout` as its parent.

The problem: when putting this component on a form, after pressing ALT-F12 to enter the source editor for the form, then pressing it again to leave it, an extra child component (`TRectangle`) for the parent is created. (the `TRectangle` shouldn't even appear in the form text editor, which I think causes the problem)

Code for the component:

```
unit Problem;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Objects;

type
  TProblem = class(TLayout)
  private
    rect: TRectangle;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('FMX Problem Component', [TProblem]);
end;

{ TProblem }

constructor TProblem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  rect := TRectangle.Create(nil);
  rect.Parent := Self;
end;

end.
```

I'm sure the answer is trivial, but would appreciate it nevertheless.

Comment: Don't publish it. If it's in the parent's protected or private sections, it shouldn't be available outside that class and therefore won't show in the tree.

Comment: It's in the parent's private section. Odd thing is that it doesn't appear when I put the component on a form, but does appear in the Structure Tree when I load a project with such a component on its form.

Comment: I must be doing something horribly wrong. Each time I press Alt-F12 to view the form source and Alt-F12 to leave it, it creates a new instance of the TRectangle...

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: You're doing something horribly wrong. Unfortunately, no one here can tell you what it might be, because we can't see your screen from where we're sitting and you've posted zero lines of code here.

Comment: Perhaps you should *not* set `csSubComponent`. If you didn't anyway, then forget about this comment.

Comment: I didn't set csSubComponent (don't want to stream), but tried with it set nevertheless. No difference. At the moment I'm trying to figure out why the destructor of the main component doesn't get called after an Alt-F12 + Alt-F12, and, if unsuccessful, make a demo with minimal code, before wasting any more valuable time of any illustrious Overflowers.

Comment: (edit: I just found out it does get called, and even with an explicit rect.Free, an extra component gets added each time)

Comment: Actual component code shown. And question radically altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Stored := False for the rect:

```
constructor TProblem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  rect := TRectangle.Create(nil);
  rect.Parent := Self;
  rect.Stored := False
end;
```

SetSubcomponent seems to be handled incorrectly in FireMonkey.